# updating jetty servlet 9.2.2 to 9.3.8

Tags: maven, servlets, jetty, jetty-9

I'm trying to update jetty server and servlet from version 9.2.2 to version 9.3.8
after updating my pom.xml file i get some errors like ServletContextHandler and ServletHolder are not found !

here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
    </dependency>
```

and this is my JettyServer class

```
public static void start() throws Exception
{
    Server server = new Server(Configuration.getInstance().getPortServer());

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");

    ServletHolder h = new ServletHolder(new HttpServletDispatcher());
    h.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "de.jettyserver.Services");
    context.addServlet(h, "/*");

    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
    server.join();

    LOGGER.debug("JettyServer started");
}
```

and the errors

```
[ERROR] /C:/..../jettyserver/JettyServer.java:[4,33] package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet does not exist

[ERROR]/C:/../jettyserver/JettyServer.java:[5,33] package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/../jettyserver/JettyServer.java:[27,17] cannot find symbol symbol:   class ServletContextHandler location: class de.tuberlin.snet.sonic.jettyserver.JettyServer

    [ERROR] /C:/../jettyserver/JettyServer.java:[27,53] cannot find symbol symbol:   class ServletContextHandler location: class de.tuberlin.snet.sonic.jettyserver.JettyServer
[ERROR] /C:/../jettyserver/JettyServer.java:[27,75] cannot find symbol symbol:   variable ServletContextHandler location: class de.tuberlin.snet.sonic.jettyserver.JettyServer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in your dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId> <!-- not plural! -->
    <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks alot. actually i copy it from the jetty website  
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets/9.3.8.v20160314

Comment: that's not jetty's website.  the eclipse jetty project recommends use of [search.maven.org](https://search.maven.org/) over mvnrepository.com (which is wildly inaccurate and misleading)

Comment: oh ok ! when i google it the first website was mvnrepository.com. thank you for the information

Comment: Wow, I lost a long time thinking my bazel rules were wrong, so confusing :(